# Audio signal comparison from Radar

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I an working on a student project. We have a radar that gives an audio detection using headphones to indicate the type of target. Target types are (eg car/truck/man). Radar distinguishes between these targets based on doppler variation, down converts this into audible range and operator can hear it through headphone. System has provided sample audio files corresponding to each type of target(man/car/truck) to train the operator to know as to what he is hearing when live signal is fed and accordingly decide what target it is.

I intend that a software can do the job of this operator.

I want to compare live audio signal input from Radar with 7 different test audio files and want the software to tell me which file matches the input.

kindly educate me .... can these audio fingerprinting softwares do my job.

Comment: It can most certainly be done, but it will not be easy unless you know a good deal about audio processing. So to educate yourself you should start read books about digital signal processing.

Comment: I don't see a programming question in here. In particular, I don't see anything C++-related here. This isn't even sufficiently researched to be on-topic on our Digital Signal Processing StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to be done can  be implemented in [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org), in a lot of ways.

You could, for example, take the audio signal as input to an `audio source`, connect that to a set of `xlating FIR filters`, which you'd design using the `gr_filter_design` tool; you then would estimate the (potentially decimated) signal in these bands by converting the complex samples to their power (`complex to Mag^2`) and would then further low-pass and decimate, to then select the band with the highest energy. All this can be done in a nice graphical way in the GNU Radio Companion (`gnuradio-companion`), which will then generate Python code, which is used to set up the signal flow graph based on the C++ GNU Radio framework.

I recommend you read the [Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials) and see where you get from there.